# finding longest sequence of consecutive numbers

Tags: java, arrays

Problem H (Longest Natural Successors):

Two consecutive integers are natural successors if the second is the successor of the first in the sequence of natural numbers (1 and 2 are natural successors). Write a program that reads a number N followed by N integers, and then prints the length of the longest sequence of consecutive natural successors.

Example:

Input 7 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 Output 3 this is my code so far and i have no idea why it does not work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(array(array));

    }

    public static int array(int[] array) {
        int count = 0, temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            count = 0;
            for (int j = i, k = i + 1; j < array.length - 1; j++, k++) {
                if (Math.abs(array[j] - array[k]) == 1) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    if (temp <= count) {
                        temp = count;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return temp + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is 5 6 7 = 3? not the correct answer?

Comment: @KevH yes this answer is correct but my program is not returning it

Comment: Code reformatted using [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) by pressing <ctrl><a> <alt><shift><f> and then <tab>.

Answer (score 2):

Why two loops? What about

```
public static int array(final int[] array) {
    int lastNo = -100;
    int maxConsecutiveNumbers = 0;
    int currentConsecutiveNumbers = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == lastNo + 1) {
            currentConsecutiveNumbers++;
            maxConsecutiveNumbers = Math.max(maxConsecutiveNumbers,
                    currentConsecutiveNumbers);
        } else {
            currentConsecutiveNumbers = 1;
        }
        lastNo = array[i];
    }
    return Math.max(maxConsecutiveNumbers, currentConsecutiveNumbers);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the final `Math.max`.

Comment: I initially thought so, too - but I need it for the case of N=1.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
public static int longestConsecutive(int[] array) {
    int longest = 0;
    // For each possible start
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Count consecutive.
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            // This one consecutive to last?
            if (Math.abs(array[j] - array[j - 1]) == 1) {
                // Is it longer?
                if (j - i > longest) {
                    // Yup! Remember it.
                    longest = j - i;
                }

            } else {
                // Start again.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return longest + 1;
}

public void test() {
    int[] a = new int[]{7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10};
    System.out.println("Longest: " + Arrays.toString(a) + "=" + longestConsecutive(a));
}
```

prints

```
Longest: [7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has "Problem H" associated with it, I'm assuming you are just learning.  Simpler is always better, so it usually pays to break it down into "*what* has to be done" before starting on a particular road by writing code that approaches the problem with "*how* can this be done."

In this case, you may be over-complicating things with arrays.  A number is a natural successor if it is one greater than the previous number.  If this is true, increment the count of the current sequence.  If not, we're starting a new sequence.  If the current sequence length is greater than the maximum sequence length we've seen, set the max sequence length to the current sequence length.  No arrays needed - you only need to compare two numbers (current and last numbers read).

For example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

 int N = scan.nextInt();

 int maxSequenceLen = 0;  // longest sequence ever
 int curSequenceLen = 0;  // when starting new sequence, reset to 1 (count the reset #)
 int last = 0;

 for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     int cur = scan.nextInt();
     if ((last+1) == cur){
         ++curSequenceLen;
     }
     else{
         curSequenceLen = 1;
     }
     if (curSequenceLen > maxSequenceLen){
         maxSequenceLen = curSequenceLen;
     }
     last = cur;
 }
 System.out.println(maxSequenceLen);
```

Caveat: I'm answering this on a computer that does not have my Java development environment on it, so the code is untested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this question correctly. The answer's written here assumes that the the natural successors occur contiguously. But if this is not the same then the solution here might not give the correct answer.

Suppose instead of `[7 2 3 5 6 7 9 10]` the input was `[7 2 6 3 7 5 6 9 10]` then the answer becomes `2` while the natural successor `[5 6 7]` is present in the array.

If the input is not sorted we'll have to use a different approach. Like using `HashSet`

1. Load the entire array into a `HashSet` which removes duplicates.
2. Pick the first value from the `HashSet` and assigned it to `start` and `end` and remove it from the set.
3. Now decrements `start` and check if it is present in the `HashSet` and continue till a particular value for `start` is not present int the `HashSet`while removing the value being searched from the set.
4. Do the same for `end` except that you will have to increase the value of `end` for each iteration.
5. We now have to continuous range from `start` to `end` present in the set and whose range is `current_Max = end - start + 1`
6. In each iteration we keep track of this `current_Max` to arrive at the longest natural successor for the entire array.

And since `HashSet` supports Add, Remove, Update in `O(1)` time. This algorithm will run in `O(n)` time, where `n` is the length of the input array. 
The code for this approach in C# can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7453286/3575018)